number of solution of $x_1^2+\cdots+x_k^2=c$
number of solution of $x_1^2+\cdots+x_k^2=c$,where $x_i\in Z_{2^a}^{\ast}$.
I have calculated some examples.
When $a=1$,then the equation has solution iff $k=c \pmod 2$ and the only solution is $(1,1,1,\cdots,1)$
When $a =2$, then $Z_4^{\ast}=\{1,3\}$, so $x_i^2=1$, so when $k=c \pmod 4$, there are $2^k$ solutions.
When $a =3$,then $Z_8^{\ast}=\{1,3,5,7\}$, so $x_i^2=1$,so when $k=c \pmod 8$, there are $4^k$ solutions.
But when $a>3$, $x_i^2=1$ don't hold, so the number of solutions can’t be the form like $n^k$, I am trying to use gauss sum to calculate but it works when we calculate mod odd prime. It’s very hard to compute for mod $2^n$.
Can anyone give some good solution?

I guess the answer is $4^k$ plus or multiple a power of 2 related to k and a but I can’t find the clear formula.

When a=1, shouldn't (1,1,...,1,0,0) also be a solution?

$Z_2^{\ast}$ only have 1 element $1$

Oh, I see, thanks!

Maybe it would help to write the number of solutions as $\sum_{y_1+\cdots+y_k=c} s(y_1)\cdots s(y_k)$, where $s(y)$ is the number of square roots of $y$ modulo $2^a$ (for $a\ge2$ this is either $4$ or $0$). That reduces the problem to counting solutions to a linear congruence, where the variables $y_i$ satisfy additional conditions.

When $a\ge3$ you have $x^2\equiv1\pmod8$ for all $x$. Furthermore, if $b\equiv1\pmod8$ the equation $x^2=b$ has exactly four solutions $x\in\Bbb{Z}_{2^a}^*$. So if $b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_k=0$, where $b_i\equiv1\pmod8$ for all $i$, you get $4^k$ solutions $(x_i)$ such that  $x_i^2=b_i$.

when$a=4$,$x_1^2+x_2^2=2$has more than 16 solutions,so must plus something on$4^k$

When$a>3$,it seems that there are $2^{(k-1)(a-3)}$ ways to use $k$ numbers which is equal to 1 module 8 to have $c$ and $c+2^a$,and each way have $4^k$solutions as he said before.so the answer is $2^{2k+(k-1)(a-3)}$, am I right?
